# Implement two Providers in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, auth0

I am attempting to implement a Redux store into my react application. I am using Auth0 for Authentication and Authorization. I need to store data such as UserID and permissions into my store. Currently my index.js file is as follows:

```js
// src/index.js

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Auth0Provider } from "./react-auth0-spa";
import config from "./auth_config.json";
import history from "./utils/history";
import {createStore} from "redux";
import rootReducer from './redux/reducer';
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

//create Redux store
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

// A function that routes the user to the right place
// after login
const onRedirectCallback = appState => {
  history.push(
    appState && appState.targetUrl
      ? appState.targetUrl
      : window.location.pathname
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  
  <Auth0Provider
    domain={config.domain}
    client_id={config.clientId}
    redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
    audience={config.audience}
    onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
  >
    <App />
  </Auth0Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Should the Provider for Redux wrap the Auth0 provider or should Auth0 wrap Redux?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter.  Everything nested inside of the two providers, regardless of which is wrapping the other, should have access to what they provide.